# How can I uninstall Ubuntu 12.04 from a dualboot (dualbooted with usbstick) Windows 7?

Tags: dual-boot, usb, windows-7, delete

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and now I want it deleted from my computer. I installed Ubuntu on a USB stick so I could dualboot my HP with windows 7 but now I want it removed. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the partition. If this is on a usb stick then format it, however if you were using grub, and it was installed to the MBR you will need to boot into the windows install disk, and use the startup repair option, to restore window's boot code,
A nice guide is here. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/20864-mbr-restore-windows-7-master-boot-record.html

to remove a partition from a HDD simply use fdisk, or some other tool, like partition magic for windows, conversely if Linux was installed on a separate HDD, then simply remove the disk, or format it.

Since you weren't too specific, if you want windows removed, then I would suggest installing Linux over it with a live CD, or not so sure about this but i believe you usb stick might have an option to install to hard disk some where in it's GUI-land.